# What's the trex querystring parameter for Google Search URLs

Tags: google-search

I have a small database with URLs for Google Reviews, many of which are for `https://www.google.com/search?q=...`.  Of the 1,010 links, 680 have a `trex` querystring parameter.  Some example values:

- trex=m_t
- trex=m_t:lcl_akp,rc_f:
- trex=m
- trex=m_t:lcl_akp,rc_f:nav,rc_ludocids

My searching is turning up nothing helpful.  What does the trex parameter mean / do?

Example full URL:
https://www.google.com/search?q=the+bat+cave&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS777US777&oq=the+bat+cave&aqs=chrome..69i57.18467j0j9&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x886b4ed2e7cc3285:0xe456fcca4e9b3f57,3,,,&trex=m_t:lcl_akp,rc_f:nav,rc_

Comment: Are you able to share one of the full URLs?

Comment: @TomFaltesek Added full example to question.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still not sure of their purpose or meaning, but technically those are not querystring params. They take place after the `#`, which means they are [fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: When I navigate to that URL, I don't see any reviews. Is that expected?

Comment: @TomFaltesek When I open it, there's a review modal that pops up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypKuG.png

Comment: My guess is that Google is using fragment identifiers to keep track of certain modal-specific state in the URL. I don't believe those fragment identifiers were intended to be completely bookmarkable. It seems that one of those items (probably `lrd`) helps identify who opened the modal. I'm not logged in as you, so it doesn't work. Try opening that URL in a browser that you haven't used to log in to Google and see what happens.

Comment: @TomFaltesek Still a modal, but asks to login instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af0lC.png

Comment: Interesting. I've tried in a few browsers and I'm not seeing a modal. Perhaps the business you are reviewing doesn't show for me because of location-based search results. I don't get any business results at all.